# Limitation in changing from email address from out-going emails

Tags: approval-process, assignment-rules, email-alert

I noticed that for some out-going email we are not able to change from email address like the following:

1. Approver notification email from approval process.
2. Assignment notification email from Assignment Rule.

I do not have any option to update it.

Any idea about the possibility of changing this? or can not we do that?

Answer (score 2):

for the Assignment rule there is a way to change the from email address instead of having only no-reply@salesforce.com.

uncheck 'Send Case Notifications from System Address' in support settings, then it will use **Automated Case owner** users email address. this is an organization wide, not specific to particular assignment rule.